Show that $r(X,Y)=0$ when Y is a function of X.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. Then a measure called conditional residual extropy, defined as
$$J(X|Y)=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \bar{F}^2(x|y)dx, \hspace{2mm}y>0$$ where $\bar{F}_{X|Y}(x\mid y)=P(X>x\mid Y>y).$
Define $$r(X,Y)=1-\frac{J(Y|X)}{J(Y)},$$
where $J(Y)=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \bar{F}^2(y)dy,$ $\bar{F}(x)=P(X>x)$. $\bar{F}$ is the survival function.
Proposition: Let $X$ and $Y$ be nonnegative absolutely continuous random variables. Then
$$r(X,Y)=\begin{cases}0& X\text{ and }Y\text{are independent},\\
1&Y\text{ is a function of }X.
\end{cases}$$
I want to prove this proposition (link of the paper is given here please see the paper for more information. I want to prove proposition 6). When $X$ and $Y$ are independent it is easy to show that $r(X,Y)=0$. I am having problem with how to show that $r(X,Y)=1$ when $Y$ is a function of $X$. Did the author miss to assume something here?

Posted last week (and edited multiple times since then, and so now bearing a different title) on stats.SE.

I don't understand what $J(X|Y)$ means: notice that the expression on the RHS integrates over $x$, but not $y$, so this varies as a function of $y$. But there is no $y$ on the left hand side. Is there also an integral over $y$? Or should I think that you're defining $J(X|Y = y),$ and subsequently you're interested in the random variable $J(X|Y),$ where $Y$ is random? Or something else entirely?

There is no integral over $y$. You're taking correctly. I am defining for $J(X|Y=y)$.

Okay, but what is $J(X|Y)?$ Is it a random variable? Is it $\mathbb{E}_y[J(X|Y = y)]$? In either case, you should edit the question so that at least the functionals in it are clear.
